# Python - TKinter - Treeview alignment text from Column #0

Tags: python, tkinter, text, treeview, alignment

How can I align the text form the element #0 of my TreeView?

```
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure('Estoque.Treeview', rowheight=44)
    tree = ttk.Treeview(frame4, columns=("#1","#2"), selectmode='none',  style='Estoque.Treeview')
    tree.heading('#0', text='Foto', anchor='center')
    tree.heading('#1', text='Produto', anchor='center')
    tree.heading('#2', text='Quantidade', anchor='center')
    tree.column("#0", anchor='center')
    tree.column("#1", anchor='center')
    tree.column("#2", anchor='center')
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.produtos ORDER BY nome_produto ASC")
    lista = []
    for a in cursor:
        tree.insert('', 'end', text='**Align this Text**', value=(a[1], a[2]))
```

When I run this code the result is this [image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: It would help to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), in particular, the database part is irrelevant here, use dummy data instead. What do you mean by "align the text in column #0"? `'**Align this Text**'` is centered in column #0 already

Comment: With this code the text in column 0# is aligned in the left.

Comment: On my computer, the text is centered in column #0 (Linux, tk8.6.11, python 3.9.6)

Comment: Seems like the `anchor` option does not apply on column `#0` (the *tree* column).

Comment: Do you really need column #0? Because if you just want a table (no subitems), you can just use columns #1, #2, ... and hide column #0 using the option `show="headings"`

Comment: "On my computer, the text is centered in column #0 (Linux, tk8.6.11, python 3.9.6) – j_4321 19"
I´m using Python 3.8.0, PyCharm 2020.3 on Win10.

Comment: I´m using Python 3.8.0, PyCharm 2020.3 on Win10.

I want add some images in columns #0 of TreeViewe. But my problem is only the alignment. There´s another way to do that?